# Stronger than strict convexity, bounded hessian?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis

I've encountered a condition similar, but slightly stronger, to that of a function being strictly convex. The condition is

$\phi(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda \phi(x)+(1-\lambda)\phi(y) - \frac{c(1-\lambda)\lambda}{2}\|x-y\|^2 $

where $c>0$ constant and $\forall\lambda \in[0,1]$. I believe that this condition is equivalent to that all eigenvalues of the hessian of $\phi$ are bounded from below by some positive constant. But I have not been able to prove it.

Appreciate all answers!

Comment: Could you elaborate more on `bounded from below`? They are always non-negative because you function is convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\psi(x) = \phi(x) - c \|x\|^2$.  Then your condition says that $\psi$ is convex, which is equivalent (assuming twice differentiability on a convex open set) to the Hessian being positive semidefinite.  The Hessians of $\phi$ and $\psi$ differ by a constant.

Comment: This actually gives me more than I wanted in the first place, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to fix $\lambda=0.5$, $z=\frac{x+y}{2}$ and $h=\frac{x-y}{2}$. Then your condition rewrites
$$f(z+h)+f(z-h)-2f(z)\ge C\|h\|^2,$$which is equivalent to say that
$$\frac{Hess_z[f](h,h)}{\|h\|^2}+\mathcal O(\|h\|^2)\ge C$$ which implies that eigenvalues of hessian are not less than $C$.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted to find.